# zip a list in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, scrapy

i made a **scraper** for yelp. The timings are **scraped** in the list and then zipped together to add a pipe (|) sign between between them. But the problem occurs when there are two timings for a single day like

```
Fri
8:00 am - 12:30 pm
5:45 pm - 7:00 pm
```

and the next day has single timing:

```
Sat
8:00 am - 1:00 pm
```

so it zips the list something like `Fri 8:00 am - 12:30 pm | 5:45 pm - 7:00 pm, Sat| 8:00 am - 1:00 pm`
so i need a method to zip it appropriately, so that it writes the pipe sign at appropriate position.

**The expected out-put:**

```
Fri 8:00 am - 12:30 pm, 5:45 pm - 7:00 pm | Sat 8:00 am - 1:00 pm
```

so that it knows where does the day end and put the pipe sign there.
Following is the code implemented for extracting the timing and zipping it:

```
timings = response.xpath('//table/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
timings = [i for i in timings if 'now' not in i]
timings = list(zip(timings[::2], timings[1::2]))
timings = ' | '.join(str(elem) for elem in timings).replace("'", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
```

I will be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: What is the expected output for the example Fri record?

Comment: edited, kindly check

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple like this

```
mystr = 'Fri 8:00 am - 12:30 pm 5:45 pm - 7:00 pm Sat 8:00 am - 1:00 pm'
mystr = mystr.replace(' S',' | S')
mystr
>>> 'Fri 8:00 am - 12:30 pm 5:45 pm - 7:00 pm | Sat 8:00 am - 1:00 pm'
```

Comment: it is extracted as a list not string as the scrapper is made using scrapy, moreover there are other days too...so only replacing the S of Sat with | s wont work